# Echoing text after redirect

Tags: php, redirect

So I'm trying to echo some text after the redirect, I'm trying to create a script that changes the first name and last name from the database (EASY). I want to tell the user after they clicked `Save changes` button, A message, That says:

> Your name has been updated successfully!

**But** after the redirect or page refresh in this case, The reason that I'm redirecting the user is, I want to prevent the form to be resubmitted.

Here is my code so far:

```
// If the query was successfull
if ($name_change) {

    $header = header( "refresh:1;url=settings.php" );                   
    $this->messages[] = "Your name has been updated successfully!";

} else {
    $this->errors[]   = "There was a problem while settings your new name.";

}
```

Comment: your code make no sense

Comment: You should use jquery and Ajax to do this. And your provided code unable to understand. Please provide full code. and explain it.

Comment: for one, `header` sends an HTTP header `refresh:1 ..` is not one

Comment: :/ So that's why you guys down-voted, Basically the `$this->messages[] = "...";` It will output to the screen whenever I set a value to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't POST to the same page that displays the form. Always POST to a page that accept's the request, then redirects to the correct location. For a loose example:

- **form.php** generates the HTML view and form. The form has `action="post.php" method="POST"` and POSTs to *post.php*.
- **post.php** accepts the $_POST data and deals with it. If the POST data is wrong, then **post.php** does a header redirect back to *form.php* so the user can resubmit. If the POST data is correct, then whatever action is needed is done with the data, and then there is a header redirect to *success.php*.
- **success.php** outputs the *Your name has been updated successfully!* message.

No amount of refreshing in this method will ever allow the form to be resubmitted.